# Laravel 8 Vue Package Could Not Find a Declaration Module

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-8

I'm trying to create a table view with laravel framework using jetstream inertia js vue package, and came across `revogrid` npm package, so i installed it using the vue 3 version.

Installation went fine, but when i imported the component, it gives me `Could not find a declaration module for '@revolist/vue3-datagrid'` and after `npm run dev` no changes happened.

my container.vue :

```
<template>
    <app-layout>
        <template #header>
            <h2 class="font-semibold text-xl text-gray-800 leading-tight">
                Customer
            </h2>
        </template>

        <div class="py-12">
            <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
                <div class="bg-white overflow-hidden shadow-xl sm:rounded-lg">
                    <v-grid
                        theme="compact"
                        :source="rows"
                        :columns="columns"
                    ></v-grid>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </app-layout>
</template>

<script>
    import AppLayout from '@/Layouts/AppLayout'

    export default {
        data: function () {
            return {
                columns: [{ prop: "name" }, { prop: "details" }],
                rows: [{
                    name: "1",
                    details: "Item 1",
                }]
            }
        },
        components: {
            AppLayout,
            VGrid
        },
        methods: {
            fetchCustomer: function () {
                axios.get('/api/customers')
                .then(response => this.rows = response.data)
                .catch(error => console.log(error))
            }
        },
        created: function () {
            this.fetchCustomer()
        }
    }
</script>
```

error :

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9m9hq.png)

result is empty page, while expected result is a sample table

Comment: `npm i @revolist/vue3-datagrid --save;` run this

Comment: @KamleshPaul yes sir, i've tried that but still no difference